# How can I test on a device I don't have?

Tags: testing

I received a report that my application fails to run on a specific device (smartphone).

However, not only I don't have access to that device, but they're also quite rare, and I'm not going to buy one just to fix this problem.

Unfortunately, it is imperative that I support that device, as it is a requirement to get published on a store I need to publish on.

Do you guys have any ideas on what can you do when you need to test on a device you don't and can't have?

Comment: using the emulator, or borrow one.

Comment: @Tordin Nobody I know has such a device...

Comment: What device is it exactly? Do you have any description of why your application fails and how it fails?

Comment: @RoyT. Sony Xperia Play. I have to support it to get onto PSM. It failed, and they (Sony) didn't say why. They just said it crashed.

Comment: You should probably outsource the test. Go to the phone providers website and look for forums where you might find some willing (free) participants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a [tip/trick](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/511079/Free-virtual-test-devices) on CodeProject that discusses this very problem.

Samsung are essentially providing free access to actual devices via the web [over here](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/), I'm not sure if the same thing is provided by any other vendors though.

Comment: Wow, those test devices look awesome!

Comment: That is pretty much awesome. Sony doesn't seem to have one for their devices though...

Answer (score 1):

If this is an android phone then you can run an emulator, with the same screen size and stuff as the device you want to test on.
It will not be perfect but it will let you see if the screen-size is the problem (which is could be) and you can change other setting in making the emulator.

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

That might help you. If it is not android there may be other emulators out there for iOS and Windows ect...

Comment: It is Android, but I don't think it's the screen size, because I've tested on many devices with several screen sizes. Unfortunately some Android devices are very heavily customized, so unless I either have the specific android image for that device to test on the emulator (unlikely), I won't be able to reproduce the problem